# Visual Studio 2015 crash when opening solutions as administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2015

1. Open VS 2015 as administrator
2. Open a solution
3. Projects in solution are listed with status Initializing, then suddenly VS crash.

Everything works as normal when NOT running as administrator

Tried:
- Disable all extensions
- Run VS in /safemode /log
- Examine ActivityLog.XML, but nothing special in there
- Debug crashing VS gives me:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled Message: An
>   unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

There is no more information, I have no idea about what library causes this. Any suggestions???

EDIT: It is probably related to a failed uninstall of VS 2013 yesterday. Although strange that the two versions affect each other in that way. My next move will be to try a repair of VS 2015.

Comment: Why do you need to run visual studio as administer?

Comment: To publish web apps to remote server with "Web Deploy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair of VS 2015 fixed the issue and even allowed 2013 to be successfully uninstalled.